# Cannot import python API module

Tags: python, api

I am trying to use a python `API` module to obtain satellite information. The module is called **spacetracktool** ([link to module](https://pypi.org/project/spacetracktool/)). I was following the documentation on the attached page and installed it using `pip`. Now when I try to import it using `import spacetracktool as st` it gives me an error saying

```
def __init__(self, username: str, password: str, fmt: str=None):^                           
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried this on two different devices and I still get the same error (Note I already have an account at space-track.org as the documentation suggests.)

Comment: Please post the _full_ error message

Comment: What is your exact Python version? Check please, don't assume.

Comment: Please create a virtual environment either with `virtualenv` or `conda` (say, `st_env`). Activate `st_env` and install `spacetrack` and other relevant libraries. Then test out the package again. The package `spacetrack` supports python 3.3, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7. So, as long as you have the supported python version installed in `st_env`, you should be fine. This will also contain all wanted/unwanted consequences within the environment, `st_env` you just created.